# Why Wildfly says that at deploy my REST resource file is annotated with @RequestScoped, however it is not?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, jboss-weld

I have a REST service implemented by Resteasy. In the service I inject (by Guice) an application (implements business logic and has injected EJB too) which has @EJB injected. When I deploy it Wildfly 10 gives me the exception at the bottom.

Just searching for the error message I have found that I might have CDI (Weld?) misconfigurated.

```
 [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 9) WELD-000167: Class digitallibrary.masterdata.dataservice.rest.api.resources.CurrencyResource is annotated with @RequestScoped but it does not declare an appropriate constructor therefore is not registered as a bean!
```

I have a few questions because I'm new at this area, and I need some direction to move forward because I don't know whether I haven't read something to have this app up and running and I met a strange case.

- How Weld comes into picture around @EJB? I know somehow my session bean is injected, but I had the feeling it happens without any configuration needs.
- Why Weld thinks that my CurrencyResource class is annotated? It is not.
- Does it always need configuration? I have checked Wildfly examples project on Github and I haven't seen configuration.
- Do I have to use beans.xml?
- It is possible that nested injection causes this problem?
- do you need any other code sample from my project?

Please find my application code below:

Resteasy resource class:

```
@Path("/currency")
public class CurrencyResource {

    private final CurrencyAppInterface currencyApp;

    @com.google.inject.Inject
    public CurrencyResource(final CurrencyAppInterface currencyApp) {
        this.currencyApp = currencyApp;
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/currencies")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Response getCurrencies() {
        System.out.println("stuff");
        Collection<String> currencies = new ArrayList<String>();
        currencies.add("curr1");
        currencies.add("curr2");

        return Response
                .status(Response.Status.OK)
                .entity(currencies)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Resteasy application file:

```
@ApplicationPath("/api")
public class DigitalLibraryMasterDataDataservice extends Application {

    private Set<Object> singletons = new HashSet<Object>();

    public DigitalLibraryMasterDataDataservice(@Context ServletContext servletContext) {
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons(){
        Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new CurrencyModule());

        CurrencyModule currencyModule = injector.getInstance(CurrencyModule.class);

        singletons.add(currencyModule);

        return singletons;
    }
}
```

Application file, implementing business logic and using the session bean.

```
public class CurrencyApplication implements CurrencyAppInterface {

    @EJB(name = "CurrencySessionBean")
    private CurrencySessionBean currencySessionBean;

    private CurrencyMapperInterface currencyMapper;

    @com.google.inject.Inject
    public CurrencyApplication(CurrencyMapper currencyMapper) {
        this.currencyMapper = currencyMapper;
    }

    @Override
    public Collection<CurrencyDto> getAllCurrencies() throws DigitalLibraryMasterDataDataserviceApplicationException {

        try {

            Collection<Currency> currencies = this.currencySessionBean.getAllCurrencies();
            Collection<CurrencyDto> mappedCurrencies = this.currencyMapper.MapCurrenciesToCurrencyDtos(currencies);
            return mappedCurrencies;

        } catch (Exception e) {

            throw new DigitalLibraryMasterDataDataserviceApplicationException("Error in application", e);

        }
    }
}
```

The Session Bean:

```
@Stateless
public class CurrencySessionBean implements CurrencySessionBeanLocalInterface {

    @PersistenceContext(name = "DigitalLibrary.MasterData.Dataservice.PU")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public Collection<Currency> getAllCurrencies() throws DigitalLibraryMasterDataDataserviceEjbSessionBeanException {

        try {

            List<Currency> currencies = this.em.createQuery("from Currency", Currency.class).getResultList();
            return currencies;
        } catch (Exception e) {

            throw new DigitalLibraryMasterDataDataserviceEjbSessionBeanException("Error querying currencies", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Full error message from Wildfly:

```
22:56:25,818 INFO  [org.hibernate.envers.boot.internal.EnversServiceImpl] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) Envers integration enabled? : true
22:56:26,117 WARN  [org.jboss.weld.Bootstrap] (Weld Thread Pool -- 9) WELD-000167: Class digitallibrary.masterdata.dataservice.rest.api.resources.CurrencyResource is annotated with @RequestScoped but it does not declare an appropriate constructor therefore is not registered as a bean!
22:56:26,275 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-5) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."DigitalLibrary.MasterData.Dataservice.ear".WeldStartService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."DigitalLibrary.MasterData.Dataservice.ear".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
        at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Injector with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.parentInjector
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.parentInjector(GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.java:0)

        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:359)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:281)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:155)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:518)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
        at org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:63)
        at org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:56)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
        at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)

22:56:26,279 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (DeploymentScanner-threads - 1) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "DigitalLibrary.MasterData.Dataservice.ear")]) - failure description: {
    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"DigitalLibrary.MasterData.Dataservice.ear\".WeldStartService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit.\"DigitalLibrary.MasterData.Dataservice.ear\".WeldStartService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001408: Unsatisfied dependencies for type Injector with qualifiers @Default
  at injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject private org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.parentInjector
  at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.guice.GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.parentInjector(GuiceResteasyBootstrapServletContextListener.java:0) "}, "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" =>["jboss.deployment.unit.\"DigitalLibrary.MasterData.Dataservice.ear\".WeldStartService"], "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => undefined }
```

Comment: jax-rs spec says Services must have a no-arg constructor. Change CurrencyResource  to use field injection instead of constructor injection.

Comment: Out of curiosity, Is there a reason you're using Guice instead of just the default Java EE CDI? I'm not familiar with wildfly/weld, but I thought Weld was JBoss/Wildfly's implementation of injection which would remove the need for Guice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all answers!

There were many problems in my code:

- not all code implementing some business logic were annotated by @EJB
- I wanted to inject the by Guice and somehow the imports were mixed
- there was an @EJB injection where I referenced the class instead of interface

What I did to solve this:

- I refactored by business logic classes and all of them are stateless session beans
- they can be easily included by CDI and Guice is not needed anymore
- I fixed the reference problem too

It works no well.

Answer (score 1):

First, your constructor is annotated with

```
@com.google.inject.Inject
```

That is definitely not right.The [Inject](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/package-summary.html) annotation comes from javax.inject package.

Secondly, your bean must have a constructor without arguments. If you wish to @Inject something via your constructor, it must be a bean CDI knows.

You can try:

- Removing the argument from the CurrencyResource constructor.
- Fixing @Inject annotation (javax.inject package)

Comment: Beans with constructors taking arguments is allowed per the CDI spec. Only JAX-RS resources are required to have a no-arg constructor. His problem is caused by that and mixing Java EE plain CDI and Guice.

Comment: I am saying exactly what you do in the " If you wish to @Inject something via your constructor, it must be a bean CDI knows" part.

Answer (score 1):

To your answer your question from the title: In WildFly by default (if CDI and JAX-RS are enabled), any JAX-RS resource is analyzed by a CDI extension and if it's not annotated with a scope annotation, `@RequestScoped` is added automatically.

Also support for **constructor injection** of JAX-RS resources is optional, i.e. not required by the spec. and I'm not sure whether RESTEasy supports this... I think it does not.

Answer (score 1):

This is only an addition to the previous answers.

When you change your constructor to take no arguments you can also move your inject to an init method instead of inject-by-field. This is how we do it in my company and we also use wildfly 10 with standard CDI.

That would like like this:

```
public CurrencyResource(){
}

@Javax.inject.Inject
public void init(final CurrencyAppInterface currencyApp){
  this.currencyApp = currencyApp;
}
```